# Create Android project minimum sdk api 11 import also action bar library

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Why if i try to create a project with min sdk Api 11, eclipse also import the action bar library and create the project using appcompat?
In the android developer guide, it says that the library and appcompat are used only if the project is below Api 11.

Comment: what is your problem exactly what you wanna do?

Comment: You won't need support library if your min apk version is 11. Its features will already be there in sdk. For support below 11, you need appcompat.

Comment: Hi, yes, iknow i don't need the support library. But i wonder why eclipse create the project using appcompat and add the support library if i choose a min sdk of API 11. They should be not implemented